# VT100 positioning outside of the terminal's window

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape, vt100

Some time ago I designed the telnet client, having 80*24 window size. Now I have a bug report, and it became clear that server positions the cursor out of the window - at the line 25. My client displays black lines, while Windows telnet seems to skip number of lines required to position to the desired line - in this case - automatically adds 25-24=1 blank line, and sets cursor at the last line 24 before displaying anything else.

I can not find any information how telnet client must behave when server positions cursor out of the window using `Esc [ Line;Column H` or `Esc [ Line;Column f`. All the sources I researched just state something like "Moves the cursor to row n, column m. The values are 1-based, and default to 1 (top left corner) if omitted."

Comment: That (indexing) is a documented feature of VT100s.